# Calculating the coordinates of the selected pixel point from an image with known corner coordinates

Tags: gps, georeferencing, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

[image]How can I calculate the coordinates of the point(P) we want from an image with known corner coordinates?
[image]

I want to find out respective coordinates from the selected the pixel of the image obtained while looking at the earth from the drone. First I'm trying to find the corner pixels' coordinate then the selected pixel coordinates by using ratio proportion. I need an algorithm to find the respective coordinate. Can someone walk me through this process?